# CheckBox in android gridview not working on first click

Tags: android, checkbox, android-gridview

am doing an android application, in that am loading check boxes in grid view from JSON web services . Up to this it is working perfectly. when i click the check box for the first time it is not triggering the event. but the second time it is working properly. Please help me if anybody knows

My java Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showFolderPopUPforEdit() {

        int count = 0;
        String folderID = null;
        String selectedfolderID = null;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        editpopupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_folders, null);
        editpopupWindow = new PopupWindow(editpopupView,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1060);
        editpopupWindow.showAtLocation(editpopupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

        try {
            leadna_leadsFolderjsonaray = leadna_leadFoldersjson
                    .getJSONArray("folderList");
            for (int i = 0; i < leadna_leadsFolderjsonaray.length(); i++) {
                cb = new CheckBox(this);
                cb.setChecked(false);
                cb.setFocusable(false);
                cb.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);              
                cb.setBackground(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.uncheck1));
                cb.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
                JSONObject c = leadna_leadsFolderjsonaray.getJSONObject(i);
                folderID = c.getString("category_id");
                for (int j = 0; j < leadna_leadsSelectedFolderjsonaray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject arr2 = leadna_leadsSelectedFolderjsonaray
                            .getJSONObject(j);
                    selectedfolderID = arr2.getString("attach_category");
                    if (folderID.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedfolderID)) {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        cb.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.check_btn));
                        cb.setFocusable(false);
                        cb.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);  
                        cb.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cb.setText(c.getString("category_name"));
                cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                cb.setTextSize((float) 14);
                cb.setTag(c.getString("category_id"));
                cb.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(346, 90));
                cb.setPadding(54, 0, 0, 0);
                cb.setOnClickListener(this);
                cb.setId(i);
                cb.requestFocus();
                meditButtons.add(cb);
            }

            GridView gridView = (GridView) editpopupView
                    .findViewById(R.id.gridEditView1);          
            gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, meditButtons));


        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button btnSaveFolders = (Button) editpopupView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnAddActivity);
        btnSaveFolders.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        Button btnDismiss = (Button) editpopupView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                editpopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }   


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox selection = (CheckBox)v;
        //selection.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.clickfolders,0, 0, 0);       
        selection.requestFocus();       
        if (selection.isChecked() == true) {
            selection.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.uncheck1));
            //selection.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        } else {
            selection.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.check_btn));
            //selection.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  selection.getTag()+ " was pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My Layout XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_black_transparent_90"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/FOLDERS"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_red_edit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="EDIT"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridEditView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"        
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >
    </GridView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_red_cancel_47"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddActivity"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_red_ok_47" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check box "+arg0.getText().toString()+" is "+String.valueOf(arg1) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  } );
```

Instead of clickListener..